# Mean free path for gas mixture

Tags: kinetic-theory

How to derive an expression for mean free path ($\lambda$) of a gas mixture with gases of different molecular mass and diameter?
What modification will be required in the general technique used by Maxwell to reach at

$$\lambda=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} n\pi d^2}$$

Where $n$ is number density and $d$ is molecular diameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It is a simple solution that I have been used.This equation may be used for all ideal gas mixtures.
The mean free path is
$$\lambda\frac{N}{V}\pi r^2 \approx 1$$
where $r$ is the radius of a molecule. This gives
$$\lambda = \frac{1}{(N/V)\pi r^2}$$

So we have
$$\lambda_t = \frac{1}{\Sigma (x_i / \lambda_i)} \\
\Sigma x_i =1$$
where$\lambda_t$ is the mean value of the multi system and $x$ is the mole fraction.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same general idea as lies behind an ideal gas calculation, with the additional factor that there are extra types of collisions to incorporate into your estimate.

Take a mixture of 50% $\rm CO_2$ and  50% $\rm He$ (by molarity).

The available collisions that may occur for $\rm CO_2$ are  ($\rm CO_2 + CO_2$) and  ($\rm CO_2+He$).

The equivent collision probabilities for $\rm He$ are ($\rm He + He$) and  ($\rm He + CO_2$).

Obviously the collisions of  ($\rm CO_2 + He$)  and ($\rm He + CO_2$) represent the same event and have the same collision rate.

Because ($\rm CO_2 + CO_2$) occurs at a slower rate than ($\rm He + He$),  the total collision rate for $\rm CO_2$ will be slower than the lighter $\rm He$.

Also, the mean velocity of $\rm CO_2$ will be slower than $\rm He$.

The mean velocity divided by the collision rate, provides the mean free path.

The source for this answer is [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/mean-free-path-for-a-mixture-of-gases.697723/)

Comment: If the mean velocity of one species is different from that of the other one then the mixture is not in thermal equilibrium, is it?

Comment: Now, TBH I have only started studying the nice ideal gases, but read this about a mixture of two ideal gases : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96089/mixing-of-ideal-gas-thermodynamic-equilibrium   intuitively I think you would have thermal equilibrium, it might just take longer to achieve than single species  ideal gases

Comment: Well, temperature is usually defined as part of the exponent in the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, and thus it uniquely determines the mean velocity of the species. That's why I don't think it's fair to use the argument that the difference in mean free path is caused by different mean velocities: if both species have the same temperature, they have the same mean velocity.

Comment: Oh hang on, that's not true! The mean velocity does also depend on the species mass, not only the temperature. So indeed, a heavier species WILL have a lower mean velocity. See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Typical_speeds)

Comment: My question, related to this, is that I know  about the Maxwell distribution for the d.o.f. related to translation, but I don't know ( yet), how you modify the distribution for the range of vibrational and rotational velocities of molecules. Slightly off topic here as regards ideal gases, sorry.